# Sort 2 arrays simultaneously by property

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays:

```
Vector3[] positions;
Matrix4x4[] transforms;
```

And a point in space:

```
Vector3 point;
```

For each position I get the distance from the point:

```
float distance = GetDistance(point, transforms[i] * positions[i]);
```

I'm comfortable enough with using delegates to sort a single array, but how can I sort the two arrays at the same time?

I need the operation to be as fast as possible, so i'd like to avoid packing into a temporary array and then unpacking the result.

I'm using .NET 2.0 so no Linq.

Comment: What do you mean by *at the same time*? Do you mean that you want elements that are initially at corresponding indices to be at corresponding indices after the sorting is done? Or do you simply want to sort both arrays?

Comment: Please provide some data for your code (input/output). Then it's easier to understand what you want.

Comment: You could try to build an array of *indices* and sort that, afterwards sort the other two arrays according to the indices.

Comment: You said you wanted to avoid a temporary array, but have you considered a mapping array. You could create an array that holds the distance and indexes into the other arrays and the sort that.

Comment: As a side note, having a temporary array will unlikely result in a noticeable performance impact. Exact opposite - trying to save on memory will result in such.

Comment: Items in both arrays correspond to each other by index, so I would like the indices to remain corresponding after the sort.

Comment: Your question makes no sense... If the arrays have parallel indexes (meaning index 1 in positions lines up with index 1 in transforms) then they always have to have the same sort order or your app breaks. Why would you need to sort them in the first place? There's so many better options like a `Tuple<Vector3, Matrix4x4>[] both` (array of tuples each of which has vector3 and matrix4x4, getting rid of these loosely connected data structures).

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Make that an answer?

Comment: @Patrick87 sure, I just chose not too because the question was so unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of managing two parallel array you should use a better model that binds the data together.

```
Tuple<Vector3, Matrix4x4>[] posTransforms;

//add like this
posTransforms.Add(new Tuple<Vector3, Matrix4x4>(vec, matrix));

// order by Y cooridinate of the vectors for example
posTransforms.OrderBy(x => x.Item1.Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to do something like what @evanmcdonnal suggests and just package the corresponding elements together (because they are obviously related and should be part of the same data structure).  Then sort them using either a built in sort function or some such thing.

If you are really opposed to doing that for whatever reason, you will need to write your own sort method that will move the elements of both arrays at the same time.

Uncompiled and untested example (but should give you a decent idea of how to proceed):

```
bool isSorted;
do
{
    isSorted = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        float distance = GetDistance(point, transforms[i] * positions[i]);
        float distanceNext = GetDistance(point, transforms[i + 1] * positions[i + 1]);
        if (distanceNext < distance)
        {
            var swapTransform = transforms[i];
            transforms[i] = transforms[i + 1];
            transforms[i + 1] = swapTransforms;

            var swapPosition = positions[i];
            positions[i] = positions[i + 1];
            positions[i + 1] = swapPosition ;

            isSorted = false;
        }
    }
} while(!isSorted);
```

Note that I used a bubble sort here (which is in no way efficient, just really easy to write).  I suggest finding a much more efficient algorithm to use if you decide to go this route.